Angular 11 - ng-dynamic-component - Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicModule
I recently migrated my application from Angular 10 to 11. The application migration worked fine. But when I tried to execute npm start, I got below error -
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicModule in C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Workspace/node_modules/ng-dynamic-component/ng-dynamic-component.d.ts'

I searched online and found below Git update -
[Bug] ERROR: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module

I tried to install ng-dynamic-component@8.0.1-no-barrels.1, ng-dynamic-component@10.0.0-no-barrels.1, , ng-dynamic-component@10.0.1-no-barrels.1, but all of them were creating different sort of errors. Below are the dependencies -
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "11.2.13",
"@angular/common": "11.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
"@angular/core": "11.2.14",
"@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
"@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
"@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/material": "11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
"@angular/router": "11.2.14",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^24.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard": "^25.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^24.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-embed": "^24.0.0",
"@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.3",
"@nasp/core": "^2.0.0",
"@nasp/tools": "^2.0.0",
"@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
"@ruf/fis-ux-assets": "4.15.0",
"@ruf/material": "^9.2.1",
"@ruf/ngx-datatable": "^4.0.1",
"@ruf/pipes": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
"@ruf/prebuilt-themes": "5.2.3",
"@ruf/rich-text-editor": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
"@ruf/schematics": "~5.2.2",
"@ruf/shell": "5.2.3",
"@ruf/splitter": "^2.1.1",
"@ruf/theming": "5.2.3",
"@ruf/widgets": "^9.3.2",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^18.0.0",
"@zeno/dashboard": "~5.0.2",
"@zeno/pipes": "~5.0.2",
"angular-gridster2": "^9.3.3",
"angular-split": "^4.0.0",
"color": "^3.1.3",
"core-js": "3.36.1",
"cross-env": "^7.0.2",
"highcharts": "^8.2.2",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.8.2",
"highcharts-custom-events": "^3.0.10",
"jsontoxml": "^1.0.1",
"jszip": "^3.5.0",
"jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"ng-dynamic-component": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
"ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
"ngx-export-as": "1.3.1",
"ngx-file-icons": "0.0.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
"ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rxjs": "6.6.7",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
"webdatarocks": "^1.3.3",
"xlsx": "^0.16.9",
"zone.js": "0.11.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.19",
"@angular/cli": "~11.2.19",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
"@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
"@ngrx/schematics": "^11.1.1",
"@nrwl/angular": "~10.0.0",
"@nrwl/jest": "10.0.13",
"@nrwl/nest": "10.0.6",
"@nrwl/node": "10.0.6",
"@nrwl/workspace": "~10.0.0",
"@ruf/wrench": "next",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jest": "25.1.4",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"dotenv": "6.2.0",
"eslint": "6.8.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"husky": "^4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"jest": "25.2.3",
"karma": "~6.4.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"ng-packagr": "^11.2.4",
"prettier": "2.0.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-jest": "25.2.1",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.3",
"typescript": "~4.1.6"
},
"husky": {
 "hooks": {
  "pre-commit": "npm run pre-commit && npm run lint"
 }
}

Please guide.
Update
Please find below the tsconfig.json file -
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "rootDir": ".",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "esnext",
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
  "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "baseUrl": "."
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
},
"exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}


Did you also try to install version 8.0.1? I saw version 8.0.1-no-barrels.1 is a bit older than only 8.0.1?

Yes I installed 8.0.1 and that's when I got the main error - Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicModule in C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Workspace/node_modules/ng-dynamic-component/ng-dynamic-component.d.ts'

Got it. Can you also share your tsconfig.json file?

I updated the description with tsconfig.json

Setting the `enableIvy' parameter to true in tsconfig.json will fix this.

I have done this already. Also following your steps, I also created a new application but only I included all my dependencies which I mentioned in the description. The newly created application worked fine without any issues at my end. And then there I get the error when I add DynamicModule to my app.module.ts. Seems like there is some incompatibility between Angular 11 and ng-dynamic-component 8.0.1

Got it. Can you set the enableIvy parameter to true in tsconfig.json and give me feedback if anything changes. I read in some issues that it helps other users.

Wow. I mean seriously wow. That worked. Why did I even kept enableIvy to false. Thank you Alex. Please post it as an answer.

It's great that it works now :)  I have updated the answer, maybe it will help someone else then.

Instead of setting enableIvy to true, I simple removed that part - "angularCompilerOptions": {   "enableIvy": false }, and it worked too.
